# keyup only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#hi").keypress(function() {
    $(".hi").html("Writing...");
});
$('#hi').keyup(function() {
    $(".hi").delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).html("");
    });
});
```

When I type like "Hello" in a textbox (#hi) the keyup only works for the first letter and then it won't disappear.

Comment: You don't really want to queue a delay of 1s on every keypress?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a timeout instead of a delay:

```
var timeout;
$("#hi").keypress(function() {
    // Clear any previous timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // Apply the writing text
    $(".hi").html("Writing...");

    // Remove the text after one second if no more key is pressed until then
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
       $(".hi").html("");
    }, 1000);
});​
```

**Here is a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tF7DH/1/

The idea here is that you set a timeout to remove the "Writing..." text one second after the key stroke. If a new key stroke is made within that second, the previous timeout is cleared and a new one is set. That way, the text will only be removed when the user has stopped typing for more than one second.

Answer (score 3):

You're blocking the [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) by not calling `next`

> As of jQuery 1.4, the function that's called is passed another
>   function as the first argument. When called, this automatically
>   dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving. We use it as
>   follows:

```
$("#test").queue(function(next) {
    // Do some stuff...
    next();
});
```